# Need to restart an Uno Platform based app

Tags: restart, uno-platform

I'm developing an App based on Uno Platform. I want to let users choose language and in order to show the new language, the app should restart. However, I can't find anything useful in Uno Platform documents. I have tried using the apis that WinUI3 or UWP apps support, but none of them work(such as `Application.Restart();` `AppInstance.Restart()` `CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync()`). Some of them request packaged environment, and others didn't exists. I don't require to use some APIs, you can give a function using Process, as long as they work well.